# calling a function in java without declaring a object

Tags: java, function-call

i am new to java is there is any possible way of calling a function within same class without creating a object for the class my program is

```
public class Puppy{

   public Pup(String name){

      System.out.println("Passed Name is :" + name ); 
   }
   public static void main(String []args){

     public Pup( "tommy" );
   }
}
```

i want to  call function pup without creating object for it ,is it possible?

Comment: Your comment in `Pup` says it is a constructor. But it isn't. It isn't a method either because it doesn't have a return type. You seem to be in a lot of confusion about Java syntax.

Comment: i know that sir but like in c/c++ is it possible to call the function without static keyword  and without creating a object for it

Comment: It is not possible to call an _instance method_ in Java unless you have an instance. This is the same in C++. If you mean standalone functions, Java doesn't have them; you have to use static methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the method to be static:

```
public static void Pup(String name){
    ...
}
```

As an aside: you should use standard Java naming conventions and start your method name with a lower-case letter:

```
public static void pup(String name){ ...
```

Comment: yes sir it works , is there is any other way without using static keyword

Comment: @ArunkarthiMani - Not without creating an object. Calling a non-`static` method requires an object (that gets bound to `this` when the method is executing).

Comment: @ArunKarthiMani since you would be printing static data, why don't you just put everything in System.out in the main method directly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Puppy{

public static void Pup(String name){
  System.out.println("Passed Name is :" + name ); 
}
public static void main(String []args){
  Pup("tommy");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define Pup as statis method like:

```
public static void Pup(String name){
  // This constructor has one parameter, name.
  System.out.println("Passed Name is :" + name );
```

}

And from main call it like:

```
Pup("tommy");
```

There are couple of issues in your code:

- You don't have valid return type for your method Pup. If you dont return anything you should add void as return type.
- You can't use public or any access modifier within any method. So you need remove public from method call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe.... 
Inside your main method, you can simply use this statement,

```
Pup("Your Name");
```

Your Pup method should have a valid return statement and use these modifiers,

```
public static
```

if it's a returning method

```
public static void
```

if it's a void method